# Django + Django Tenants + DRF API = http: error: gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tenants

Can someone please help to resolve the error i am getting?

I am using django-tenants package with DRF REST API

The issue is that accessing API VIEW via browser works fine, for example:

`http://demo.localhost:9000/api/zakaz`

But sending requests to this address via "requests" gives the error:

`HTTPConnectionPool(host='demo.localhost', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/zakaz/3/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000017E1D9FEB00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))`

Similarly and PING or HTTPIE request from console even to basic address "demo.localhost:9000" gives the same:

```
http http://demo.localhost:9000/                 

http: error: gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Couldn’t resolve the given hostname. Please check the URL and try again.
```

Meaning that this address is only resolved in browser, but not from Django or Python console..

What am i doing wrong? How do i send api request in django-tenants separately for each tenant?

I have added rest framework to TENANT APPS:

```
TENANT_APPS = (
    # your tenant-specific apps
    'rest_framework',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
    'patients.apps.PatientsConfig',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 8 hours to fix it and now - i got the issue - for some reason browser resolves wildcard subdomains from address string, but Windows fails to do so for pycharm and python..

I have edited the HOSTS file adding the subdomains

```
127.0.0.1 demo.localhost
127.0.0.1 revital.localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

And guess what? API and everything WORKS as expected...

Basically for localhost development i will have to add all possible tenant subdomains...

How do i deal with tenant wildcard subdomains in Django and not just list them in HOSTS file?

Any ideas / working solutions?

Does this happen with Linux distros?

Comment: Hi. Please update your answer and post the new questions as separate new questions if they aren't already answered. Thanks!